# template argument deduction/substitution failure in operator<<()

Tags: g++, operator-overloading

I am getting the following compiler error with a class I am trying to compile with is almost identical to another class that compiles fine.

Here is the compiler error:
spell.cpp: In function ‘std::ostream& muddify::character::operator<<(std::ostream&, const muddify::character::spell&)’:
spell.cpp:11:9: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}’ and ‘const id_t {aka const unsigned int}’)
     out <

This seems strange to me as id_t is just a typedef of unsigned int and also I have other operator overloads that are compiling fine with pretty much the same syntax. I am compiling this code under g++ version 4.9.2 on fedora 21 using the c++11 standard.

Below is my function:

```
std::ostream& muddify::character::operator<<(std::ostream & out,
                                         const muddify::character::spell& s)
{
    out <<s.id << "," << s.name << "," << s.desc
        << attribute_strings[unsigned(s.attribute)];
    return out;
}
```

I am experimenting with this project with using fully qualified namespaces for improved project management so I suspect that would be part of the issue.

If you need further code or explanations I am happy to provide that.

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 0):

The namespace experiments you mentioned sound like the issue.

The error message is complaining of a missing operator in the 'muddify' namespace, not 'std'.  In other words, you need to define that operator (or somehow point it at the one in namespace std).